# Normalizing from values [- 1, 1] to [0, 1]

Tags: javascript, normalization

This function takes value from [-1, 1] and turns value to [0, 1](it's not an array)

```
function normalize(x){
 var y = 2 * x / 2;
 return y;
}
```

With x=0.5 it would return x=0.25, but when x is 0, it returns 0, I need value 0,5.

Comment: Your function simply returns whatever is passed into it.  You are not reassigning a value to `x`

Comment: I changed it ...

Comment: Your function doesn't take an array. It takes a number.

Comment: By the way, `2 * x / 2` cancels out and reduces to `x`. Hence, your function is simply the identity function.

Comment: It's not an array, but edited question.

Comment: What you want is `const normalize = x => -(x + 1) / 2;` followed by `[-1, 1].map(normalize)`.

Comment: What's the output range supposed to be? [0, -1] or [0, 1]. There's no comma so it's hard to tell if the minus sign is supposed to be a comma or if the comma is just missing. In your question body you clearly say [0, -1] but then give an example where it's supposed to return 0,5, which is not in [0, -1].

Comment: @TedHopp It's supposed to be `[0, -1]`.

Comment: @AaditMShah - Then why does OP say that 0 is supposed to return the value 0,5?

Comment: Sorry its [0, 1]. I got the answer.

Comment: @AaditMShah - Never mind. OP just edited the question and cleared up the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize on an interval from [-1, 1], first add 1 and then divide by 2. You are multiplying by 2 and then dividing by 2, which yields the original number.

```
function normalize(x){
 var y = (x + 1) / 2;
 return y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, it's easy answer but sometimes you don't get it right away.

Comment: Negate the result.

Comment: The number is assumed to be given on the interval -1 to 1. Adding 1 transforms it to a number on the interval 0 to 2. Dividing by 2 constrains its magnitude so that it lies on 0 to 1. Negating would put the value on the interval -1 to 0, which is not that the OP requested.